# Где тут подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис

Предложение такое: "На небе ни облачка". Есть ли тут подлежащее и как вообще можно разобрать это предложение (это ни в коем случае не школьное задание - просто интересно)?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Это односоставное  безличное предложение. Подлежащего нет. *На небе нет ни облачка*. В вашем предложении сказуемое "нет" опущено, предложение неполное. От пропущенного сказуемого зависит обстоятельство "на небе" и дополнение "ни облачка".